# Do I need transit visa for 3 hours transit in Incheon

Tags: international-travel, transit-visas, icn, uzbek-citizens

I’m Uzbekistan citizenship and flying from Jakarta to Tashkent I have transit in inchong airport do I need transit visa ?

Comment: Do you mean Incheon Airport near Seoul, South Korea?

Answer (score 1):

According to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_South_Korea#Transit you don't need a transit visa for transit at the Incheon Airport if you stay less than 24 hours.

COVID-related measures have been relaxed since Oct 1, 2022.